# Mathematical background in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a philosophy postgraduate working on mathematical models in cognitive science. I would like some advice for what mathematical background I should acquire to understand the maths behind this paper of Turing's: [The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis](http://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf).

Thank you so much,

Comment: Where did all the philosophers that *had* to know basic mathematics (say, at least undergraduate level) go? I can't remember right now where (somewhere in Germany or Russia...?), but someone once told me, or I read it somewhere, that there is (are) some university(ies) that *require* philosophy undergraduates to know basic mathematics thoroughly to access to graduate school...and as the answer below remarks: to read that paper by turing you must at least know some basic differential equations and some complex analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also wonder why it's no longer (?) a requirement. Because anyway you wake up one day asking what some piece of maths is doing for your argument... I suppose most of us have to be self-taught.

Answer (score 2):

Page 39 of the publication (page 4 of the pdf) is titled "Mathematical Background Required."  By reading that and glancing at the rest of the paper, it appears that you will need differential equations, at least through solving 2nd order linear equations.

To learn DE's, you typically need two semesters of Calculus (Calc I and II).